# How to make a panel to work with a specific thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I have a lot of panels that I show them shortly and then another one. So I don't want to use a thread for every panel. is there a way to make a panel(or frame) and give a thread to its constructor so it works with it?

Comment: If your panels are independent, use `ThreadPoolExecutor` with number of threads you want to have.

Comment: What graphics library are you using? Swing and JavaFX are not designed with multiple painter-threads in mind (I suggest this is what you want to have?). Both systems, however, provide mechanisms to run certain parts of logic in different threads. Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: `I don't want to use a thread for every panel.` - why would you use a Thread for every panel? In you design you should have a "display manager" that controls which panel is displayed. So you only need to use a `Timer` in that class to control which panel is displayed. Do you even need multiple panels? Typically something like this display images so all you really need to do is update the image that is displayed on the panel.

Comment: @camickr Every panel has a thread for its self I think its name is event Queue I want that I give the first panel thread to the second one to use it

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy My problem is how to give a thread to a panel so it will use it for its self

Comment: @Hosseinmp76, there is a single `Event Dispatch Thread EDT` used by the entire GUI. If you need background processing you can create your own Thread so you don't block the `EDT`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. `to give a thread to a panel so it will use it for its self ` - still makes no sense (to me at least)?